# How update OpenSSL on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, openssl, composer-php, macos-high-sierra

If I run `openssl version` I get `OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015`.
But if I run `php -i | grep OpenSSL` I get:

```
SSL Version => OpenSSL/0.9.8zd
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
Openssl default config => /System/Library/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf
Native OpenSSL support => enabled
```

I need to upgrade OpenSSL to version 1.0.1 or above. Because I get the error below if I run

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev \
> my-dir --stability dev --no-interaction

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                     
  The "https://packages.drupal.org/8/drupal/coder%245ba3928962d22131a100415c9  
  a1a39bed3170ef1669af701b199d9cd2464e935.json" file could not be downloaded:  
   SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:                   
  error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol ver  
  sion                                                                         
  Failed to enable crypto                                                      
  failed to open stream: operation failed
```

Comment: You have clearly done something to your system. High Sierra uses LibreSSL (fork of open ssl) 2.2.7 out of the box and the PHP that ships with High Sierra uses that. You have a completely custom install going on and you need to post the details of that if you want an answer, but since you dont seem to know how to manage this custom install i would recommend just using what the system ships with. any reason why you dont?

Comment: addendum to my last comment: is it possible you are not using the latest version of High Sierra? I was assuming you were. If not, then try updating.

Comment: @BradAllred thanks for your answer. High Sierra is up to date `version 10.13.6`. I Get still the same error message. What do I have to do to fix this?

Comment: nobody can answer that without knowing what youve done to your system to end up in this position. You can always reinstall the system. You may simpley have to point composer to the system PHP instead of whatever its pointing to now.